# Adding to an ArrayList & Calling certain Strings

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, arraylist

Sorry, the question is not worded to satisfaction. Let me explain.

I am constructing a GUI which allows a user to add a new cruise to the system. on Frame 1, I have a JList which displays **just the names** of all the cruises in the system, i.e.

```
___________________
|Scottish Cruise1 |
|Scottish Cruise2 |
|                 |
|_________________|
```

Here is the code to the construction of the JList above:

```
    ArrayList Cruise = new ArrayList();
    Cruise.add("Scottish to Greek Waters");
    Cruise.add("Greek to Scottish Waters"); 

    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
    CruiseList = new JList(Cruise.toArray()); 
    CruiseList.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 200));
    scrollPane.setViewportView(CruiseList);
    CruiseList.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
    CruiseList.setSelectedIndex(-1); 
    CruiseList.setVisibleRowCount(6); 
    listPanel.add(scrollPane);
    Frame1.setVisible(true);
```

As you can see, I am storing the Cruise objects in `ArrayList Cruise = new ArrayList();`.

Frame 2, however, displays another GUI which allows the user to add a new Cruise. In order to add the new Cruise to the system, the following form elements must be completed:

```
Cruise Name: JTextField
Start Port: JComboBox
End Port: JComboBox
Start Date: JSpinner
End Date: JSpinner
Assigned to ship: JList
```

Assume the Cruise is successfully added to the system ( the new cruise objects are also being stored in the same ArrayList - `ArrayList Cruise = new ArrayList();`.

**The Question:**

I have two buttons on Frame 1:

```
1. More Details
2. List all Cruises
```

When I select a Cruise from the JList and click on "More Details", I want to output the String with all details assigned to it as output in this format:

```
Cruise Name: ________
Start Port: _________
End Port: _______
Start Date: _________
End Date: _______
Assigned to ship: ______
```

And when I select a Cruise from the JList and click "List Details" I only want it to output the Cruise Name.

Would I need two separate ArrayLists? In addition to this, how do I make it possible that when a new cruise is made successfully, it obtains **just the Cruise name** & displays it on the JList on frame1?

Answer (score 0):

There is a list model interface that could be used with **JList**. Have your list model `DefaultListModel<Cruise> cruises = new DefaultListModel<>()` that implements `ListModel` interface.

```
cruises.add("Scottish to Greek Waters"); 
cruises.add("Greek to Scottish Waters");
```

and then initiate your `Cruiselist` with new `JList(cruises)` . When you want the list to be updated with new values, update the model.